# Macbook Pro 2015 Horrible Ping w/ Slow Download/Upload Speeds

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I've been having a little issue with my wireless connection on my Macbook Pro and I can't seem to figure out what the issue is. Here's the difference in overall connection quality from my phone and my laptop.

Phone:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hTBmH.png

Macbook:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbMRW.jpg

I'm running Yosemite for anyone that's wondering, but if any of you have an idea for what the problem is please let me know! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Tether the Mac to your iPhone temporarily. You'll likely find the problem isn't the Mac but it's the service upstream from your WiFi router.